# DjangoRestFramework ModelSerializer DateTimeField only converting to current timezone at object creation

Tags: django, datetime, serialization, django-rest-framework

Update: This behaviour was recognized as a bug and resolved in django-rest-framework 3.7. Serializers will now consistently display times according to the server's timezone: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3732#issuecomment-267635612

I have a Django project where I expect the user to be in a certain timezone. I have `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'` and `USE_TZ = True` in my settings.

I have a model that includes a datetimefield. When I first create the object, the modelserializer gives datetimes with a trailing `+5:30`. Annoyingly, datetimes with `auto_now_add=True` give UTC datetimes with a trailing `Z`. I fixed this by making the field's default a callable for the current time.

If I serialize the object again at any point, all datetimes are in UTC with a trailing `Z`. From the Django documentation, I would expect the serializer to use the current timezone, which defaults to the default timezone set by `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'`. I have checked the current timezone in my view with `get_current_timezone_name()` and it is `'Asia/Kolkata'`. I have even tried using `activate('Asia/Kolkata')` in my view, but times are still being returned in UTC.

Note that all the times are correct (the UTC times are 5:30 hours earlier), its just that I would expect for the times to be converted. All datetimes are stored in the DB as UTC times as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield

> Signature: DateTimeField(format=None, input_formats=None)
>
> format - A string representing the output format. If not specified, this defaults to the same value as the DATETIME_FORMAT settings key, which will be 'iso-8601' unless set. Setting to a format string indicates that to_representation return values should be coerced to string output. Format strings are described below. Setting this value to None indicates that Python datetime objects should be returned by to_representation. In this case the datetime encoding will be determined by the renderer.
>
> When a value of None is used for the format datetime objects will be returned by to_representation and the final output representation will determined by the renderer class.
>
> In the case of JSON this means the default datetime representation uses the ECMA 262 date time string specification. This is a subset of ISO 8601 which uses millisecond precision, and includes the 'Z' suffix for the UTC timezone, for example: 2013-01-29T12:34:56.123Z.

So getting the UTC (Z) representation of your datetime object is in fact default behaviour.

When you **create** or **update** a model instance through Djangorest, the serializer will be called with the `data` kwarg, which doesn't happen if you use the list or detail view.

In both cases, your view will return `serializer.data`. In case of a **create/update** operation, this will be a representation of `serializer.validated_data`, while in case of a **list/detail** operation it'll be a direct representation of the instance.

In both cases, the representation is achieved by calling `field.to_representation` with the default kwarg `format=None`, which will make the field return the plain string value.

The magic happens [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/9f74b8860e64dcaeef54972db347ac1bd2afe1a3/rest_framework/fields.py#L1069):

- **create/update**: The validation returns a timezone aware object, which includes your standard timezone. It is converted to string by calling its `isoformat()` method, and returned as-is.
- **list/retrieve**: The django ORM stores the timestamp as UTC. It is converted to string by calling its `isoformat()` method, **but DRF replaces `+00:00` with `Z`** (see the link above).

So to get the desired output with timezone offset, you could pass `format=None` or a custom strftime string to the DateTimeField in your serializer. However, you will always get the UTC time with `+00:00`, because that's what the data is (fortunately) stored as.

If you want the actual offset to `'Asia/Kolkata'`, you will probably have to define your own `DateTimeField`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
class CustomDateTimeField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        tz = timezone.get_default_timezone()
        # timezone.localtime() defaults to the current tz, you only
        # need the `tz` arg if the current tz != default tz
        value = timezone.localtime(value, timezone=tz)
        # py3 notation below, for py2 do:
        # return super(CustomDateTimeField, self).to_representation(value)
        return super().to_representation(value)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why I get a different result immediately after object creation. Also, from "The current time zone is the time zone that’s used for rendering" I would assume that this either overrides JSON's "default datetime representation" or localizes the datetime after retrieval from the DB. Finally, the Django docs also explicitly specify: "When serializing an aware datetime, the UTC offset is included, like this: "2011-09-01T13:20:30+03:00"".

Comment: Think I figured it out, interesting problem.

Comment: Hmm. From the Django documentation I would be surprised if this is intended behavior, though it looks like this is an issue with Django itself and not DjangoRestFramework. I'll look into your fix.

Comment: This is very much the desired behaviour I think, see first sentence at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects Objects are stored as UTC internally, and rendered as the user's timezone ("current timezone") only in templates and forms.

Comment: It doesn't say that they are not converted for serializers. The "only" in your quote doesn't appear for me. It also seems unnecessarily confusing that the behavior would change around like this. It certainly should at least be documented. I would much prefer behavior that either always used UTC or always used the current timezone.

Comment: No I added the 'only' to make it more explicit. To me it makes sense to store UTC and render out current timezone, which can be whatever you want it to be. If you use it in Djangorest, it'll just return the DB representation. In many applications the API response will be parsed by a JavaScript library, which you can use to convert the object to whatever timezone you want.

Comment: Looks like things are working with your fix, though it will be annoying to go through and replace everything. The `to_representation(tz)` should be `to_representation(value)` though. If anyone not using python 3 needs this fix, the last line should be `return super(CustomDateTimeField, self).to_representation(value)`

Comment: cool, I updated the response above with the py2 code and the `value` :) Do please accept if it fixes your issue @JonathanRichards